# Does Delphi 10.3.2 (FMX) support the Android Talkback screen reader?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, screen-readers

I've created an Android app but a blind user wants to use it and has asked for it to support Talkback.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use AndroidTTS, Text to Speech.

All the details including the libraries used are here: [Using Delphi, I'm trying to change the volume of the AndroidTTS, but I seem to keep getting the error "External exeception 1"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64635870/using-delphi-im-trying-to-change-the-volume-of-the-androidtts-but-i-seem-to-k)

Even though I'm using Delphi 10.4.1, it should work fine for your version.

I would put my current working source codes here, but just found out they are too long for me to put them all here.  Hopefully the article I supplied you will help you create your own working AndroidTTS package so you can supply a Text to Speech for your blind user.

I'll give my friend a copy of my working source code and see if he can put it up on his github.  I'll later update this answer with the source code information.  It's a holiday, and I doubt my friend will be updating his github today.